# Set the font color of a section title formatted with leftmargin

Tags: sectioning, color, titlesec

I am trying to set the font color of a section title that is formatted with `leftmargin`. When I don't use the `leftmargin` format, the font color changes correctly, but once I add the `leftmargin` format the color remains at default black.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]   % When leftmargin is removed it works correctly
{\scshape\color{red}\fontsize{15pt}{11}\selectfont}
{}
{0.5em}                         
{}

\begin{document}
\section{Section Heading}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile your example it looks terrible (the heading overlaps with the text). Are you sure that you want to have it like this? Moreover, you can't use `\fontsize{15}{11}`. Computer Modern does not know about 15pt. It switches to `\fontsize{14}{11}` anyways.

Comment: Yeah, it is horrible. My actual document is quite a lot different - I was just using that as a minimum working example. Thanks for the info on the font size - I didn't realise that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am scared of the result. But anyway, you may use the `explicit` option of the `titlesec` package and define

```
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]   % When leftmargin is removed it works correctly
{\scshape\fontsize{15pt}{18pt}\selectfont}
{}
{0.5em}
{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%\usepackage{lmodern}    %% you may need this
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]   % When leftmargin is removed it works correctly
{\scshape\fontsize{15pt}{18pt}\selectfont}
{}
{0.5em}
{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section Heading}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also note that you got font size specifications wrong and I have corrected it.

Without `explicit` option it works this way.

```
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]   % When leftmargin is removed it works correctly
{\fontsize{15}{18}\scshape}
{}
{0.5em}
{\color{red}}
```

Also as noted by Gonzalo, `\scshape` also selects `\selectfont`

Another option is to use `\textcolor` withour `explicit` option as noted by egreg this way:

```
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]   % When leftmargin is removed it works correctly
{\fontsize{15}{18}\scshape}
{}
{0.5em}
{\textcolor{red}}
```

Also to obtain any font size load `fixltx2e` package.

Comment: Just `\textcolor{red}` is sufficient, without the `explicit` option. For "any size", load `fixltx2e`.

Comment: Thanks @Harish, that works great (and thanks for the info on the font specs).

@egreg I found that I did need to specify `explicit` for it to work (and I had to specify #1 to the "before" code of my later subsection definition for it to display properly). Thanks for the info on `fixltx2e`.

Comment: There's really no need for the `explicit` option. This is enough: `\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
  {\fontsize{15}{18}\scshape}
  {}
  {0.5em}                         
  {\color{red}` (notice also that `\scshape` makes the `\selectfont` automatically).                         
  {\color{red}}`

Comment: @egreg I have updated the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I have updated the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @egreg, @Gonzalo and @Harish. I think I've got it now: use `\color` without `explicit`, or `\textcolor` with `explicit`? That's what seems to work for me anyway. Also, when using `explicit`, `{#1}` needs to be specified in order to write the text. On a related note, there is no mention of `explicit` in the titlesec manual - am I missing something?

Comment: @abeverley I'd prefer `\textcolor{red}` *without* `explicit`.

Comment: @egreg my mistake - I thought I was getting errors when trying to do that, but I think it's because I didn't remove `{#1}` instead. Thanks.